How should I have avoided getting my ace "buried" on defense?
With neither vulnerable at duplicate, my opponents arrived at a four spade contract after a nondescript auction that disguised their strength (28 high card points between them). It was one spade (RHO), 1NT (forcing, LHO), 3 spades, 4 spades. (Defenders pass throughout.) I was the opening leader with ♠T9 ♥JT83 ♦T76 ♣AQ83.
Most people in my club would lead the ace, and probably a small club, but I elected to lead the J of hearts try to develop the suit and save the ace of clubs for re-entry. Declarer won with dummy's queen, drew trumps and gave my partner her sole trick, the ace of diamonds Meanwhile, I followed low to discourage. (Partner could see all smaller cards than my six in her hand or dummy). She still returned a diamond, allowing declarer to run dummy's diamonds, and "burying" my ace of clubs.
Should I have opened with the ace of clubs, as most club members do? Should I have relied on partner lead back a club, after she saw no future in the red suits? Or was this just an instance where a reasonable play produced a bad result? Was it more urgent to lead the ace of clubs against, say, a six spade contract, which would imply that partner might have no tricks?

Where was the king of clubs?  What was dummy's distribution?  Based on your prior questions, I strongly suspect that every single person at your club is by my standards incompetent at defense, so it's really hard to draw conclusions about correct defense in this situation.  "What is the correct defense given my partner is incompetent at defense?" is not really an answerable question.

Did declarer draw 2 rounds of trump or 3?  If it was 3, your discard on the third round should've been an important signal.  Also, I don't play it because I find it almost always just tells partner something they can already figure out, but you might want to play trump suit preference.

One more addendum: I'm sure any actual expert would consider ME incompetent at defense.  After all, at least 2 or 3 boards a session I defend as if some suit had 14 (or 12) cards in it.

Give. The. Auction! Making opening lead decisions without the auction is tantamount to sticking one's hand, blindfolded, in a bowl of piranha- unlikely to provide a pleasant result.

Confucius say: "Defender who lead same suit as Declarer, be partner of partner of fool."

@ForgetIwaseverhere: The auction was one spade (RHO), 1NT (forcing, LHO), 3 spades, 4 spades. (Defenders pass throughout.) I added this line to the question. Opposing clubs were 3-2, with  KJX in dummy. After partner took the ace of diamonds, and returned one, dummy ran diamonds, allowing declarer to sluff both clubs.

What was dummy?  Should it have been obvious that dummy could run diamonds?  If there was a third round of trumps drawn, what signal did you give when you discarded?

You don't give the auction, so it's difficult to judge the lead. You don't give the dummy or the number of rounds of trump pulled, so it's difficult to judge partner's play.
Giving me this hand without the auction, I find little fault with the lead of the heart jack. The ace of clubs seems likely to lose more often than it wins (again, without knowing anything about the auction) and I don't see any particular reason to play it.
However, your play of a low diamond does not show negative attitude towards diamonds. We don't generally give attitude when opponent leads a suit because (a) it is assumed that we do not want to continue the suit, since declarer is playing on it and (b) telling declarer the location of missing honors in a suit that they are playing on is much more helpful to declarer than partner. In standard signaling, you are indicating that you started with an odd number of diamonds (which happens to be true).
When declarer gives you a trick in a side suit, it is not often correct to continue playing that suit. There are exceptions, but think about why, when you are declarer, you play on a side suit. It's often to set up winners in that suit so that you can pitch losers in another. Indeed, that seems to be the case in this hand: once declarer knocked out the diamond ace, they were able to pitch away club losers (I assume). Partner was almost certainly wrong to continue a diamond, even without knowing about your club ace.

Auction analysis
Some inferences can be made from the auction. I have never played (or played regularly against) the forcing 1NT and/or 2/1-flavored systems. I will go with the internet’s description; in a real situation, make sure to ask opponents (once the auction is over) about the precise meaning of their bids.

1♠: 5 spades, 11+HCP
1NT: 6-12HCP, 2 or fewer spades, kind-of regular hand, forcing for one round
3♠: game proposal - 6 spades (at least) and 15-18HCP

without game force (<14HCP) they would bid 2♠
with game force but no hope of slam (something like 18-20HCP without good shape?) they would jump to 4♠
with a hope of slam (20+ points counting shape) they would/should investigate at the lower levels


4♠: to play: 10-12HCP and probably 2 spades.

That auction is "nondescript" in the sense that it gives no obvious hints at what side colors the declarer will use, but it is rather precise in terms of strength of either opponent. I grant you that you have no real idea of the shape of the hands; a fifth-card side color in dummy is possible, though unlikely.
Scoring system
A previous version of this answer assumed the scoring system is IMP. In that case, beating a beatable contract is much more important than limiting overtricks of a cold contract: compared to a line that ensures =, giving an overtrick is -1 IMP, beating a NV game is +10 IMP. Hence a line that gives a 10% chance of beating and a 90% chance of giving an overtrick is worth taking.
In MP, things are very different: if everyone in the field makes =, taking a non-standard line ensures a top or bottom, so you should only take it if it is above 50%.
The competition situation matters too. If you scored 30% in the first half of a MP event, or -30IMP in the first half of an MP event, and you try to end up at least on average, you will need to take some pretty crazy decisions in the second half; sound, safe bridge in a mediocre field might score you 55% / +3 IMP on every board but that is not enough to climb back. (In statistics terms: you switch to a lower-mean, higher-variance strategy - some math here). Here, as the competition situation is not given, I shall ignore it.
Opening lead
We see 7HCP in our hands, from the auction partner must have between 4 and 7.
First of all, there is a rule of thumb to lead away from your honors (unless those honors are a sequence). The reason for that rule is to avoid giving a free finesse to your opponents. The obvious application here is if declarer has the ♣K: leading any club allows them to take a trick with it, when they would never be able to do so otherwise. But it also applies if dummy has the ♣K. Sure, if declarer takes the club finesse (after another lead) it will work, but maybe they must then choose between the club finesse (which you know works) and another line (which may or may not work; for instance, they might try to finesse the ♥K in your hand). Leading clubs makes the choice for them (even if you lead a small one, they have no other choice but to try the king if they want to not lose two tricks in the color).
It seems players at your club did not apply that rule of thumb. Let us look at the situation more specifically.
Consider first the active / aggressive lead hypothesis. Something needs to be done urgently, else declarer might discard the problematic cards on a side color. What could this be? I see two possibilities:

partner holds the ♣K, and both opponents hold at least three clubs, and the opponents can discard a club on a red suit if they are in hand. In this case, leading clubs is urgent.
declarer holds the ♣K, and both opponents hold at least two clubs, and we can establish a red honor in partner's hand if we lead the appropriate color. (Additionally, partner needs to play well and can go through declarer for two club tricks.) In that case leading clubs just gives a trick and possibly two (it allows declarer to take a trick with the ♣K and loses a tempo to establish partner’s red suit).

The former is much less likely than the latter with regards to the layout of clubs; even taking into account that you need to guess the correct red color in the latter, it is still a superior play, under the hypothesis that an active lead is needed.
What about a passive lead? Well, the rule of thumb applies here. Leading away from ♣AQ will give a free finesse for the ♣K in declarer’s hand, which is moderately likely (they have the hand with most HCP). Leading in another suit might give a trick, but it is more speculative - it needs to be a color where the declarer can finesse partner, and where would have not done so on another lead. Imagine for instance declarer has ♥AQ ♦xx opposite dummy's ♥xx ♦AKxx with three losers in the black suits (three clubs, or two clubs and the ♠Q offside). Sure, leading hearts "gives" the finesse, but the declarer had no choice but to try it anyway.
Finally, what about a trump lead? As an active lead, that does not seem indicated (again, check this with your local 2/1 expert, but the auction does not scream "ruff in dummy" to me). As a passive lead, this fails if partner holds ♠Qxx. Surely that is similar to the situation in the red suits? Well, not really. Declarer can bury a red honor by running the other red suit, but they cannot bury a trump honor. Hence, playing a red suit is better.
Which red suit? All other things being equal, we would rather lead a suit that is less likely to be held by the opponents. This means our longest suit (mechanically, if we have more, they have less of it), and majors (which are more likely to be named during auction if held by them).
Hence, I agree with your heart lead (which card exactly would depend on defense conventions; in my regular partnership the jack is indicated). Leading a small diamond would be acceptable at my level. A trump is dubious. The ♣A is incorrect, and a small club is atrocious (this might give one trick and no losers to declarer with the ♣K).
Partner gets in hand
After losing one heart and three spade tricks, declarer leads diamonds. You play low, dummy plays (say) the jack. (If you played low when dummy has no honor, that is a mistake, you should have played the ten.) Partner takes the ♦A; can she beat the contract?
All three remaining tricks need to come from your hand. Partner started with 5HCP (the ♦A and a black jack); by the same auction analysis as above, and removing the ♥J that you played, she can infer you have 5-8HCP among ♥K ♦KQ ♣AQ:

spades have been played and you had nothing;
you would not lead the ♥J with the queen or ace;
she can see ♣KJ in dummy.

At that point, she can see the contract is unbeatable. The only way to put three "natural" tricks in your hand, given that clubs are offside, is ♥K ♦KQ in your hand. This is the maximum that you can have in terms of points, but even so, that requires that hearts be played once and diamond twice without allowing declarer to establish a ruff in either color, when they have all club honors. This requires declarer’s hand to be three clubs (else they pitch something on dummy’s third club), two hearts (else they take the ace and ruff the next round) and three diamonds (else they ruff the third round); this is impossible given that they have shown six spades at auction (3+2+3+6=14).
Given that, she must play to limit declarer to =. What exactly this means depends on what she sees in dummy, but:

if declarer had been able to quickly discard diamonds, they would have been able to do so rather than play diamonds, so we can assume there is no urgency in diamonds;
the only important honors to "score" are therefore the ♥K and ♣A.

establishing the ♥K from your hand requires two rounds of the color, with the first one not being played from your hand
establishing the ♣A from your hand requires one round of the color, from any hand.



Therefore I think the correct card is likely to be hearts. This assumes that (from partner’s perspective) the ♣A in your hand is not much more probable than the ♥K. I believe this to be the case, but a better player than me might show otherwise.
In practice this would have buried your hand all the same, i.e. "a reasonable play produced a bad result". Your suggestion to return a club, while inspired by frustration at your hand, is in my opinion incorrect. (Whether diamonds or clubs is the "more incorrect" play, I leave it to others to discuss.)
Against 6♠ (or 7♠)
The auction would be entirely different, and as a consequence, so would be the information you have.
For instance:

did partner double a conventional bid to request a certain lead? Or did they have the opportunity to do so, but failed to take it?
did either opponent name a control in clubs? If so, first-round (i.e. a void) or second-round? Which opponent? If you know the ♣K is onside, you may have a chance to beat the contract (if your partner gets in hand via a queen and goes through RHO, or if declarer needs to establish a trick in clubs), but you need to not lead the color.
can you tell partner is club singleton or void in a red suit? 1♣ - 1♠ - 2♠ - 3♣ (etc.) shows both opponents 4-4 in black colors, which means your partner is club singleton. This almost never happens but when it does you must pay attention.
opponents might announce whether a trump lead is safe (one of the replies to RKC Blackwood is "I have three cards among the aces and the king of trumps, plus the queen of trumps"; if their partner bids six, you know that they have AKQ of trumps). You might still need an aggressive lead to beat the contract, but you know trump is safe.
does the auction call for an aggressive lead? That is a vast subject and I am by no means an expert, but compare those extremes:

1♠ - 4♦ (Splinter) - etc.:  There is a high risk that the contract makes through ruffs, discards etc. An aggressive lead is called for.
1NT - 2♣ - 2♠ - etc.: Regular hands, calling for a safe lead is called for.




The comment " However, given the scoring system, beating a beatable contract is much more important than limiting overtricks of a cold contract. Hence, let us assume the contract is beatable." is completely false. Unless stated otherwise, one must assume a Duplicate game is matchpoints, where it is vital to not make avoidable errors, such as over-aggressive opening leads.

Re: 4S. Since partner has shown ~15-18, 4S can't be 10-12; if that were the case, you would stop in 3S in many making games. I'd say it's more like 8-12.

A thorough answer. I agree with @ForgetIwaseverhere's comment regarding scoring. Your analysis of partner's return decision is good but omits any discussion about signaling to previous tricks that may help partner here. For example, many pairs play trump suit preference; even giving diamond count might help partner better picture the hand. Of course all of this is made more difficult because the dummy is not given in the question.

@ForgetIwaseverhere My bad, I think that’s a translation/culture issue on my part. In France, the vast majority of tournaments are either 4-person teams with IMP scoring ("duplicate"), or 2-person teams with MP scoring ("pairs"). I incorrectly assumed IMP scoring. I edited the post (it does not change the decisions though).

@ruds I disagree on the auction: assuming the player who bid 1NT has no distributional values (again, I might be wrong, as I do not play against 2/1), they should not bid game with 8-9 HCP opposite a maximum of 18. (I agree on the importance of reading partner’s signals.)

@UJM: In 2/1, the 1N bid is 6-12, usually 0-2 spades (but could be 11-12 with 3 spades), and the 3S bid is more like 17-18, (since responder can invite over a 2S rebid with 2+ spades and 10-12).  1N is not always balanced - it could contain a long suit other than spades without enough strength to make a game forcing bid (since 2C/D/H responses are all game forcing)

In your "Partner gets the hand" analysis -- this is presumably after 3 rounds of trump, so the querent has had a discard, which should have been a club to indicate that he held clubs rather than hearts/diamonds.
